# Al generar excel desde PHP, dejar archivo en el servidor

Tags: php, excel

estoy generando una tabla de excel desde un archivo de PHP y me funciona correctamente. El problema que tengo es que yo quiero que el archivo excel generado se quede en el mismo sitio donde esta el archivo PHP, y no que se descargue (Mi intención es ejecutar este archivo como tarea programada)

Este es mi código:

```
<?php 
include "../clases/conexion_publica.php";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
//He probado cambiando el Content-Disposition por inline, pero hace lo mismo, descarga el archivo
//header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$filename);
$libros = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM articulos");
$linea = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ) {

    //Y Ahora los montamos 
            $datos = array(
                'IdAdticulo' => $rows['id'],
                'Descripcion' => $rows['nombre'],
                'Descripcion1' => $rows['descripcion'],
                'IdFamilia' => $rows['id_familia'],
            );
$libros[] = $datos;

}

$mostrar_columnas = false;
$array_creado = array();
 

    foreach($libros as $libro) {
        if(!$mostrar_columnas) {

            echo implode("\t", array_keys($libro)) . "\n";

            $mostrar_columnas = true;

        }

    echo implode("\t", array_values($libro)) . "\n";

    }

 exit;
```

Como he indicado en el código, he probado a poner Content-Disposition: inline pero hace lo mismo, descarga el archivo. ¿Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Pero es que lo único que estás haciendo es añadir el archivo para que se descargue. Quieres que se guarde pero en ningún momento estás creando un archivo en el servidor. Lo que necesitas no es cambiar los `header()` (que sirven para modificar la página que vas a mostrarle al usuario nada más, no para crear archivos...). Lo que necesitas es [crear un archivo en php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp). Buscar en la documentación de vez en cuando no hace daño, es la mejor manera de aprender. Y cambiar cosas a lo loco no suele funcionar en programación, la documentación es lo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de:

1. Tener permisos para poder escribir en el directorio que quieres crear el fichero.
2. Crea un un fichero simple, no tiene porque ser un fichero Excel, un fichero de texto txt sería suficiente.
3. El contenido que quieras escribir en la Excel, podrías tenerlo de manera temporal en memoria, en un vector / contenedor y después pasar este contenido al fichero Excel.

Antiguamente creaba ficheros CSV que los podrás abrir con Excel sin problema y posiblemente te de menos problemas a la hora de crearlos.